# Term for a function that is an involution on its image

Tags: functions, terminology, definition

Is there a specific term for a function $f:X\to X$ that obeys the law $f^3(x)=f(x)$? It's not necessarily an involution, but it is an involution when its domain is restricted to its image.

A simple example is the function $f:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3\}$ defined by
$$
1\mapsto2, 2\mapsto3,3\mapsto2
$$

Comment: Using the example given, the image of $f$ is $\{2,3\}$. If $f$ is restricted to its image, i.e., a map $\{2,3\}\to\{2,3\}$, it becomes an involution.